# Devoting RAM to specific tables in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, optimization

Is there any way that I can force MySQL to store specific tables in the RAM (other than using the memory storage engine)?

My database contains +200 GB in InnoDB tables (which I don't want to be stored in the RAM) and 10 tables (~100 MB) which uses the MyISAM engine.

My goal is to obtain the fastest possible acces to the MyISAM tables (if necessary I can change the storage engine of the MyISAM tables or move them to another db on the same server).

My db-server is running Linux and has 10 GB RAM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load a MySQL innodb database into memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486092/load-a-mysql-innodb-database-into-memory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the following:

- datadir is /var/lib/mysql
- your database is called mydb
- you have MyISAM tables t1, t2, and t3 in mydb
- you want to create a memory database called `memorydb`

You could the following:

- Step 01) `service mysql stop`
- Step 02) Create a RAM Disk
- Step 03) `mkdir /var/lib/mysql/memorydb`
- Step 04) `chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/memorydb`
- Step 05) mount the RAM disk onto `/var/lib/mysql/memorydb`
- Step 06) `service mysql start`
- Step 07) `mysql> ALTER TABLE mydb.t1 RENAME memorydb.t1;`
- Step 08) `mysql> ALTER TABLE mydb.t2 RENAME memorydb.t2;`
- Step 09) `mysql> ALTER TABLE mydb.t3 RENAME memorydb.t3;`

After step 6, `memorydb` should be registered in information_schema.schemata

If you want to keep copies of the table back in mydb, do the following after step 6

- Step 07) `mysql> CREATE TABLE memorydb.t1 LIKE mydb.t1;`
- Step 08) `mysql> INSERT INTO  memorydb.t1 SELECT * FROM mydb.t1;`
- Step 09) `mysql> CREATE TABLE memorydb.t2 LIKE mydb.t2;`
- Step 10) `mysql> INSERT INTO  memorydb.t2 SELECT * FROM mydb.t2;`
- Step 11) `mysql> CREATE TABLE memorydb.t3 LIKE mydb.t3;`
- Step 12) `mysql> INSERT INTO  memorydb.t3 SELECT * FROM mydb.t3;`

Just make sure you have enough RAM to hold your MyISAM tables.

Give it a Try !!!